# Save data to db with cron interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, cron, nestjs

I'm trying to set interval to save data once a day with cron but for some reason it's not working. Same function works fine while called from outside with postman. I've set things up according to documentation and everything seems to be ok but no data comes to db.

```
@Cron("0 0 0 * * *")

handleCron() {
        this.getTodayAPOD();
    }

async getTodayAPOD(): Promise<Observable<Promise<APOD>>>  {
    return await this.httpService.get("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?date&api_key=DEMO_KEY")
    .pipe(map(async (axiosResponse: AxiosResponse) => { 
        const newData = new this.APODModel(axiosResponse.data)
        return await newData.save();
     }))
}
```

Does any good soul here can help me solve this?

Comment: Have you tried console logging the axiosResponse.data? You might also use this construct: `const data = (await this.httpService.get(...).toPromise()).data`. Also, please **do not share your API key** to the public!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly with your construct. About api key fair point, this particular case its open api but yeah i'll keep that in mind. Thanks!